# Apply a calculation over every column

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 67 columns. Each column has heterogeneous names like "flower", "stones", "xxxx", "yyyy", etc.

I want to do the following:
iterate from the 2nd through the 67th column and replace the value of each column with the sum of its original value and the corresponding value in the first column.

As a small example, suppose the dataset only contains three columns with the following values:

```
         First Colum     Flowers       Stones
        3                   2           2 
        4                   5           3
        5                   6           1
        6                   7           9
```

After applying the desired step, it should now look like this:

```
         First Colum     Flowers      Stones 
        3                   5           5 
        4                   9           7
        5                   11          6
        6                   13          15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `dat` is the dataset

```
 dat[,-1] <- lapply(dat[,-1], function(x) x+dat[,1])
  dat
  #  First Colum Flowers Stones
  #1           3       5      5
  #2           4       9      7
  #3           5      11      6
  #4           6      13     15
```

or

```
 dat[,-1] <- dat[,-1]+dat[,1]
```