# Apply calculation over data.frame values,store in new data.frame - R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

```
> l
  var1 var2 sum
a    1    0 1
b   56    6 62
c    5    4 9
```

I want to do some calculations and make a new data.frame with the calculated values. The calculation is to divide each value of rows with the sum, so for `a` 1/1 and 0/1.

I have tried this

```
l.new <- apply(l,MARGIN = 2,FUN = function(x){x/l$sum})
#Error  in x/l$sum : non-numeric Argument for binary operator

l.new <- NULL
for(i in 1/ncol(l)){
  a <- i/l$rsum
  L2.rel <- rbind(L2.rel,a)
}
#this results in a strange data.frame...
```

So to clarify, I want `l` to look like this

```
  var1     var2    sum
a    1     0        1
b   0.903  0.067    62
c   0.556  0.444    9
```

I have seen this [Apply a calculation over every column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369476/apply-a-calculation-over-every-column), but obviously it did not work

Comment: `cbind(l[1:2] / l[, 3], l[3])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply do a division since you already have the rowSums. The below code should suffice

```
cbind(l[1:2]/l[,3],l[3])
        var1         var2 sum
a 1.000000000 0.0000000000   1
b 0.903225806 0.0967741935  62
c 0.555555556 0.4444444444   9
```

if you did not have the sums column then you could do:

```
 cbind(l[1:2]/(sm <- rowSums(l[1:2])), sum = sm)
         var1         var2 sum
a 1.000000000 0.0000000000   1
b 0.903225806 0.0967741935  62
c 0.555555556 0.4444444444   9
```

Lastly if you are only interested in the proportionality, then you could use
`prop.table`

```
prop.table(as.matrix(l[1:2]),1)
         var1         var2
a 1.000000000 0.0000000000
b 0.903225806 0.0967741935
c 0.555555556 0.4444444444
```

Comment: Just for future readers: ```l``` should be a df, when it is a data.matrix the 1st solution does not work.

Comment: @takeITeasy, YOU SHOULD USE `l[,1:2]` instead and it will work irespective of it being a df or a matrix

Answer (score 2):

You may use a tidy approach with mutate_at:

```
library(tidyverse)

l %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-sum), ~./sum)
```

Or the apply-function you cited:

```
l[,-3] <- lapply(l[,-3], function(x) x/l[,3])
l
```